# Have element dimension units ever been discussed as part of a CSS spec?

Tags: css

Something that I sometimes find myself needing when building for the web is to size one dimension of an element relative to the current value of another dimension of the same element.

For example let's say we have a design that calls for perfectly square tiles and each row has 4 tiles. At the moment in a design with a maximum width (1140px, 960px, whatever your flavour is), we can hardcode the height of each tile by dividing the total width of the container by 4.

```
// css
.container
{
    width: 1140px;
}

.tile
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 285px;
}
```

However once we get to the container width breakpoint the width of the tiles becomes a percentage of the container, which means that the height is no longer going to match.

So we need to add some javascript that takes the current width of each tile and applies it as the height. We also need to have this occur on window resize and if we're being conscientious we need it to only work at 1140px and below (enquireJS plugin) and also we should also include it within a timeout so that it isn't firing every single pixel that we resize by.

```
// css
.container
{
    width: 1140px;
}

.tile
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 285px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px)
{
    .container
    {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tile
    {
        height: auto;
    }
}

// js (jQuery because that's what I'm using to, sorry!)
enquire.register('screen and (min-width: 1141px)', {
    match: function()
    {
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        $(window).off('resize.tile_height');

        $('.tile').removeAttr('style');
    }
});

enquire.register('screen and (max-width: 1140px)', {
    match: function()
    {
        var timeout;

        $(window).on('resize.tile_height', function()
        {
            clearTimeout(timeout);

            timeout = setTimeout(function()
            {
                $('.tile').each(function()
                {
                    $(this).height( $(this).width() );
                });
            }, 100);
        });
    }
});
```

This seems like a lot of work for such a simple desired outcome.

What I imagine would be more useful would be `ew` and `eh`, which would work similarly to `vw` and `vh` in that where `100vw` means "100% of the viewport width" `100ew` would mean "100% of this element's width"

I've searched around a fair bit and can't seem to find anything where anyone has mentioned this as a possibility. It would remove the requirement for javascript and simplify the above to:

```
// css
.container
{
    width: 1140px;
}

.tile
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100ew;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px)
{
    .container
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Is anyone aware of something like this ever being suggested or discussed? Alternatively, is anyone aware of an existing spec that would allow for the desired outcome via a different method (CSS Grid, Flexbox, etc)?

Comment: have you tried display:flex  method?

Comment: @SahilDhir Could you provide an example of how you'd achieve it using flex?

I'm not familiar with any flex rules or units that would allow me to perfectly match a flex-item's width and height. You could hack it with pseudo-elements and padding but that would still break with certain content or under certain circumstances due to flex's inherent flexibility.

Comment: can you post your html code ?

Comment: @SahilDhir I'm confused, there isn't any code, have you read the question? This is a theoretical question that is open for discussion, not something that I need help with per se.

Comment: i know you dont have any html code.. its a theoratical based qustion.. so here is the example you must read ..https://clearleft.com/posts/270

Comment: are you aware of the padding-bottom trick ?

Comment: Yeah @vals but it's more of a hack than a graceful solution. I feel like I can't be the first person to ever have the idea for `ew` and `eh` units? It seems like they would be so useful, I just can't find any discussion about them or anything similar.